# How do you re-integrate imaginary numbers after taking the derivative?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

I can take the derivative of a formula involving an imaginary number like so:
$$x=a(it)^2$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-2at$$
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-2a$$
But how would I do this operation in reverse?  How do I take the integral of the second derivative and end up with:
$$\int{-2a}\space dt=i(2at+c_0)$$

Comment: You end up with $-2at + c_{0}$, ie. the first derivative. The number  $i$ just behaves like any constant real number with respect to integrals.  The only difference being that $i^2 = -1$, which no real number satisfies.

Answer (score 2):

The integral $\int-2a dt$ is not $i(2at+c_0)$, on the left hand you have a sum of real numbers and on the right hand you have an imaginary number. It is more convenient to write $x$ as $$x=-at^2$$ by using that $i^2=-1$. Hopefully this clears your doubt since you are actually just dealing with real numbers.